# Изменить рейтинг конкурсного вопроса

Tags: предложение, вопросы, конкурс

Есть ли возможность повысить рейтинг конкурсного вопроса после того как уже назначил награду?

Т.е. сейчас мой вопрос в конкурсных с наградой в 100 голосов за него, а хотелось бы повысить до 300, например, чтобы увеличить интерес!

Comment: Только после завершения текущего конкурса, насколько я знаю.

Comment: можно попросить модераторов отменить текущий конкурс и начать новый. Назначенная репутация, возможно, будет потеряна

Comment: Штатными способами точно нельзя. Можно модераторов попросить.

Comment: @D-side можно штатными. Но надо быть в штате :) А кандидаты больше не принимаются.

Comment: @Grundy Репутация потеряна не будет. Модератор имеет техническую возможность отменить конкурс, репутация при этом возвращается.